# How do I make a second POST to a webserver?

Tags: java, html, cookies, protocols, httpurlconnection

I have a website which I'm trying to log-on to and fill in forms automatically and then finally sending the data. The first step is achieved with the code below i.e. I can log in and then redirect to the page I'd like to fill with information.

The code gets the form name and value and changes these using GET and POST and I'd like to repeat this process but this time with multiple forms (instead of just username and password). I manage to get the form name and values and change the HTML but the issues occurs when I try to POST the new values back to the server. I don't get any error messages and the code returns the new page but the form data remains unchanged.

I can't seem to find the issue in my code, the second process works just like the first process, the only difference is, I now try to POSTdata to multiple forms.

The problem, I assume, lies either in my `fillFormParams` or `sendPost` methods. I appreciate any help!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
public class HttpUrlConnectionExample {

  private List<String> cookies;
  private List<String> cookiejar;
  private static HttpURLConnection conn;


  private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String url = "http://www3.bagerisystem.se/webbordersodervidingebagarn/Logon.aspx";
        String menuPage = "http://www3.bagerisystem.se/webbordersodervidingebagarn/Meny.aspx";

        HttpUrlConnectionExample http = new HttpUrlConnectionExample();

        // make sure cookies is turn on
        http.createCookieManager();

        // 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
        String page = http.GetPageContent(url);
        String postParams = http.getFormParams(page, "****", "****");

        // 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
        // authentication
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        http.sendPost(url, postParams,conn);

        // 3. success then go to menuPage.
        String result = http.GetPageContent(menuPage);
        //System.out.println(result);

        // 4.Send new GET request
        String page2 = http.GetPageContent("http://www3.bagerisystem.se/webbordersodervidingebagarn/Retur.aspx");
        //System.out.println(page2);
        int[][] returVal = {   { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, },{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, },{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, },{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, },{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, },{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, }};
        String postParams2 = http.fillFormParams(page2, returVal);
        // 5. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
        // authentication
        String url1 = "http://www3.bagerisystem.se/webbordersodervidingebagarn/Retur.aspx";
        URL obj1 = new URL(url1);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj1.openConnection();
        http.sendPost(url1, postParams2,conn);
        // 6. success then go to menuPage.
        String resultz = http.GetPageContent("http://www3.bagerisystem.se/webbordersodervidingebagarn/Retur.aspx");
        System.out.println(resultz);
    }

  private void sendPost(String url, String postParams,HttpURLConnection conn) throws Exception {

    // Acts like a browser
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www3.bagerisystem.se");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }

    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www3.bagerisystem.se/webbordersodervidingebagarn/Logon.aspx");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    // Send post request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = 
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
//   System.out.println(response.toString());

  }

  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();


    // default is GET
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    // act like a browser
    conn.setRequestPropert`enter code here`y("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }
    }
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
//  System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
//  System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // Get the response cookies
    setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

    return response.toString();

  }

  public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)

        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    //System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    //  form id
    Element loginform = doc.getElementById("Form1");
    Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
    List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
        String key = inputElement.attr("name");
        String value = inputElement.attr("value");

        if (key.equals("UserNameTextBox"))//If corresponding input form is found, enter defined username
            value = username;
        else if (key.equals("PasswordTextBox"))//If corresponding input form is found, enter defined password
            value = password;
        paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
    }

    // build parameters list
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String param : paramList) {
        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result.append(param);
        } else {
            result.append("&" + param);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  public List<String> getCookies() {
    return cookies;
  }

  public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
    this.cookies = cookies;
  }
  public void createCookieManager(){
      if (cookies == null) {
      CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
      }
      }
  public String fillFormParams(String html, int[][] returVal) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
      //Form id

      int row = 0;
      int column = 0;
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      Element inputForm = doc.getElementById("Form1");
      Elements inputElements = inputForm.getElementsByTag("input");
      List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
      while(row <5 ){
      for (Element inputElement: inputElements){
          String key = inputElement.attr("name");
          String value = inputElement.attr("value");
          String truId =  "ReturDataGrid:_ctl" +(row+2);
        //  "ReturDataGrid%3A_ctl2%3AtxtAntal_1" + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("1", "UTF-8")
          String newId = truId + ":txtAntal_" + Integer.toString(column);
          if (column == 6) {
                 row++; 
                 column = (column+1)%7;
        }
          if(key.equals(newId)){
              key = "ReturDataGrid%3A_ctl"+(row+2) +"%3AtxtAntal_1" +column;
                value = Integer.toString(returVal[row][column]);
                 paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
            }    
      }
      column++;
      }
        for (String param : paramList) {
            if (result.length() == 0) {
                result.append(param);
            } else {
                result.append("&" + param);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get? some error message and description would be helpful

Comment: No error message, it just doesn't post the information into the form as it should.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Is a particular line of your program misbehaving?

Comment: This line in my sendPost method  generates an error  the second time around.    for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }'. The problem is the form data on the website is not updated with the new values from the fillFormParams method. They are, however updated in sendPost method, so I suspect that the error occurs when the new values are being posted to the website. They are updated  the first time I call the sendPost method (used to log into the website) but not when I try to sendPost the second time around.